# Can .attr be animated?

Tags: jquery, iframe

Is it possible to animate `.attr` function in jQuery? I have an iframe that changes the width and height of a video based on a click. I have to use `.attr` to change with the width and height of the iframe because I have css code that makes the iframe responsive to a screen's browser.

```
<iframe id="video-ply" src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_embed_url', true ) ;?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" width="615" height="346"></iframe>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#video-ply").attr('width', '889px');
$("#video-ply").attr('height', '500px');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of using `.attr` try to change the class of your iframe,

$("#video-ply").addClass("animate");

then on your css file,

create a class named `.animate`

```
.animate{
    width: value;
    height: value;
    /* css transition effects here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply a transition via css. Then, when it changes height/width, it will transition at the speed you want instead of instantly:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wxfwvmb/1/)

```
#video-ply {
   transition: 1s;
}
```

You can also individually control each attribute's speed, delays and transition types if needed:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wxfwvmb/3/)

```
#video-ply {
    transition: height 2s .4s ease, width .5s 1s ease;
}
```

---

Also, you can just use jquery's `.height()` and `.width()` instead of using the `.attr()` and chain them as well:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wxfwvmb/4/)

```
$("#video-ply").height('200px').width('200px');
```

Or use `.css()`:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wxfwvmb/5/)

```
$("#video-ply").css({
    'height': '200px',
    'width': '200px'
});
```

Or just toggle a class a new class and have a stylesheet do everything for you.